# Following Allan Storm's tutorial and I encountered a problem in Part 5

Tags: module

Well, I am just learning to create modules, I am currently doing the part 5 of AllanStorm's tutorials this is the link:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

I am currently in the part of adding the  inside the config.xml, the code says the following:

```
<global>
<!-- ... -->
<models>
    <!-- ... -->
    <weblog_resource>
        <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource</class>
    </weblog_resource>
</models>
</global>
```

yet following the tutorial, I don't know what  is, and where should I place everything inside the config.xml, currently I am trying to add it like the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <TBGTEST_Helloworld>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </TBGTEST_Helloworld>
</modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>TBGTEST_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
        <models>
            <helloworld>
                <class>TBGTEST_Helloworld_Model</class>
                <!--
                need to create our own resource, can't just
                use core_resource
                -->
                <resourceModel>helloworld_resource</resourceModel>
            </helloworld>
        </models>
    </frontend>
```

at the same time I don't know what the  tag means, i am sorry if this is so basic, I tried to discuss it in the tutorial but the discussion box at the bottom is deactivated. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config.xml file should be following

```
<config>
<modules>
    <TBGTEST_Helloworld>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </TBGTEST_Helloworld>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <helloworld>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>TBGTEST_Helloworld</module>
                <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
            </args>
        </helloworld>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <helloworld>
            <class>TBGTEST_Helloworld_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>helloworld_resource</resourceModel>
        </helloworld>
        <helloworld_resource>
            <entities>
                <tablename>
                    <table>table_name</table>
                </tablename>
            </entities>
        </helloworld_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Take a look following link which can help you to understand config file tag

[magento module configuration file reference](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/08/31/magento-module-configuration-file-reference.html)